# Can you combine ctrl with mouseenter in jQuery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, keypress, ctrl

I am making a little game with jQuery, and I wondered if it is possible to fire an event on hover and/or mouseenter when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind `mouseenter` and `keypress` event for element on which you want things to work out.

```
$( "#id_of_element" ).bind('mouseenter keypress', function(event) {
if (event.ctrlKey)//check if cntrl key is pressed
{
//your code here
}
});
```